# .Net standard/core version of system.web.http.HttpError

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, migration

While migrating form .net Framework to .net Standard/Core
I came across the HttpError class.
I can't find any equivalent in .net core/standard except of the Compatability Shim which is just a temporary solution.

Do you know if there is an official replacement for it? Maybe  the API has changed and there is a new best practice to use instead of HttpError.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpError object provides a consistent way to return error information in the response body. In asp.net Core Web API, you can define a base ApiResponse class like :

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public int StatusCode { get; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Message { get; }

    public ApiResponse(int statusCode, string message = null)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Message = message ?? GetDefaultMessageForStatusCode(statusCode);
    }

    private static string GetDefaultMessageForStatusCode(int statusCode)
    {
        switch (statusCode)
        {
            ...
            case 404:
                return "Resource not found";
            case 500:
                return "An unhandled error occurred";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also derive this class to define more specific predefined error types, please refer to [this](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/handling-errors-in-asp.net-core-web-api) and [this](https://medium.com/@matteocontrini/consistent-error-responses-in-asp-net-core-web-apis-bb70b435d1f8) article for more details and code sample .

Edit :

From version 2.1 ,it added support for [RFC 7807 – Problem Details for HTTP APIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) as a standardized format for returning machine readable error responses from HTTP APIs:

Reference : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-web-apis/

Comment: What do you think of the 'ProblemDetails' which is added to core MVC 2.2? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @Yogev . Oh,yes, from version 2.1 , it supports for [RFC 7807 – Problem Details for HTTP APIs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7807) as a standardized format for returning machine readable error responses from HTTP APIs. I will update the reply . Thanks for prompting .