# What is the alternative for System.Web.Http.HttpError class in .NET 5?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I am migration our old API from ASP Web API to .Net 5 core and I found the usage of HttpError class.

```
var httpError = new HttpError(exception, true);
```

I have checked Microsoft official documentation and did not find any suggestions how to replace the legacy. Please suggest the alternative for HttpError.

Thanks

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649867/net-standard-core-version-of-system-web-http-httperror) may helpful.